# Is it possible not to display data in ZoomBandChart, but still use it as a multi-graph zoom controller?

Tags: lightningchart

I want to use the zoom bar chart as a multi-graph zoom controller. However, I don't want to display the series (content of the graphs) inside the ZoomBandChart, or maybe another series that has nothing to do with the rest of the graphs.

One ugly solution has been to fill the ZoomBandChart with the same color as the series, but I still can see the shadow of the series on it. I'm attaching a screenshot.

Any solution?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jID56.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting use case,

First thing that comes to mind is adding any empty series to each X axis, and add those to the zoom band chart. Currently zoom band chart synchronizes every axis of the series attached to it.

EDIT: of course, you can also just hide the Zoom band chart series. For example:

```
zoomBandChart.add(myLineSeries).setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
```

This of course results in some extra processing for the charts, but I think it should be fine especially if you use the newest series type, `PointLineAreaSeries`. It is very well optimized with Zoom band chart.

https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/more-guides/beta-xy/